# SPARK: Understanding coalesce method?

Tags: java, apache-spark, coalesce

i'm trying to understand the coalesce method in spark.

I have a `JavaRDD<String>` (which consist of 16310 Strings) and I want to save it in 233 files. (one file with 70 strings)

First, i tried it with `trainDataFeatures.repartition(233).saveAsTextFile(outputPathTrainFeatures);`

This works well, but i don't want to shuffle my data. so i tried it with: `trainDataFeatures.coalesce(233, false).saveAsTextFile(outputPathTrainFeatures);`

here i get only 4 output files. Not shuffled but only 4!!! It's really annoying. Maybe someone can help me with this issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that is the whole point and the biggest difference between `coalesce` and `repartition`.

Repartition does full shuffle of the data to be able to create those extra partitions. Coalesce moves data between exisiting partitions and avoids creating new partitions and avoids a full data shuffle.

Basically the fact that coalesce does not create the extra partitions for you is a feature of coalesce.

Same with repartition - it's able to work in a performant way thanks to a full data shuffle. You may not care about performance and just want to increase number of partitions without a shuffle - well, someone had that idea before and [this issue here](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-5997) is still open.